# Entropy of RV that is function of coin flips

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory

Suppose that random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ correspond to independent and fair coin flips, i.e., it holds for their entropy that $H[ X_i ] = 1$, for all $i$.

Let $Y = f(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be some arbitrary function of these coin flips, and suppose that, for each $i$,
$$
    H[ Y \mid X_{-i} ] \ge \epsilon, \quad (1)
$$
where $X_{-i} := X_{1},\dots,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},\dots,X_n$.

My question is: **What can we say about $H[Y]$ ?**

Intuitively speaking, I would expect that $H[ Y ] \ge \epsilon n$, because (1) tells us that when we condition on everything except $X_{i}$, the remaining entropy is still $\ge \epsilon$ and this holds for all $i$. But how can I show this formally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to your conjecture. $f(X_1,\ldots,X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i (mod 2)$. Then $H(Y | X_{-i}) = 1 = H(Y)$, so that $H(Y | X_{-i}) \geq 1$, but $H(Y) = 1 \leq n$. In fact, this counterexample establishes that the trivial bound $H[Y] \geq \varepsilon$ is sharp.